# Get native window handle from Qt to create vulkan surface

Tags: c++, qt, vulkan

I am trying using Qt to present the render result of Vulkan instead of `glfw`. I known Qt offer the `QVulkanInstance` and `QVulkanWindow`, but I like to using my code to control Vulkan.

In Windows, I had got `HWND` of a `QWindow` like:

```cpp
[[maybe_unused]] auto wid = winId();
auto* platformInterface = QGuiApplication::platformNativeInterface();
auto* handle = platformInterface->nativeResourceForWindow("handle", this);
auto* hwnd = static_cast<HWND>(handle);
vk::Win32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR surfaceInfo{};
surfaceInfo.setHwnd(hwnd);
surfaceInfo.setHinstance(GetModuleHandle(nullptr));
```

And I successfully created the `vk::SurfaceKHR` using the `surfaceInfo`.

However, when I try to do this in macos:

```cpp
[[maybe_unused]] auto wid = winId();
auto* platformInterface = QGuiApplication::platformNativeInterface();
auto* handle = platformInterface->nativeResourceForWindow("nsview", this);
auto* nsview= static_cast<NSView*>(handle);
```

I got the error of `unknown type name NSView`, I thought I could use `NSView` like `HWND`, but I cannot.

I am using Qt6, I found `QMacNativeWidget` offers a `nativeView` function to return `NSView*` but `QMacNativeWidget` has been removed in Qt6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got the error of unknown type name NSView, I thought I could use NSView like HWND, but I cannot.

You should post the exact error because this sounds more like a missing include file than anything else.  Is that error happening when you're compiling or when you're actually running the app?

Additionally, `winId` should be castable directly to `HWND` on Windows and `NSView*` on MacOS:

```
auto hwnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(winId()); // On Windows
auto view = reinterpret_cast<NSView*>(winId()); // On Mac
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the right `NSView*` through `setSurfaceType(QSurface::VulkanSurface);` and `reinterpret_cast <void*>(winId())`.